# ResponseText undefined and getting json as [object Object]

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax, servlets

Okay so, I am trying to get json from servlet in the callback function in ajax. But I have used alert and it gives me [object Object]. When I check recponse text it is undefied. I don't understand I mean the code on the servlet seems good I don't know what is wrong? Thanks for the help.

My ajax

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'OtherServ',
            data: {"frameID": jsonString},
            dataType : "json",
            success :function(json,jqXHR){
                //You can also use html with hidden form
                alert(json);
                    console.log("In Ajax" +json);
                   var form = $('<form></form>').attr('action','displayform.jsp');
                   $(form).attr('method','POST');
                   var ele = $('<input type="text">').attr('name','complete_json');  
                   $(ele).val(json); 
                   $(ele).appendTo($(form));
                   $(form).appendTo('body');
                   $(form).submit();
            } ,
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                var msg = '';
                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                    msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                    msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                    msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
                } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                    msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
                } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                    msg = 'Time out error.';
                } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                    msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
                } else {
                    msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
                }
                alert(msg);
            }  
       });
```

Here's my servlet code

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
        String complete_json = new Gson().toJson(list);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Complete JSON");
        System.out.println(complete_json);
        response.getWriter().write(complete_json);
```

Comment: try [jQuery.ParseJson(json)](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

Comment: @Curiousdev, no need, it's already a JSON: `[object Object]` is a value produced by most native javascript objects' `toString()` function.

Comment: Browser documents do not natively support displaying JSON as their contents. You will need to actually explain what is it that you are trying to achieve here. Do you really want to display server response in exact same way as it came in (i.e. as formatted JSON)? Or do you actually need to display values of jsonobject somewhere on elements?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I am trying to send this json to jsp where i want to parse it and take out the values. But when I receive it in jsp their also I get the same [object Object].

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Also why is response text undefined ?

Comment: You can assume that jQuery has already converted the JSON string to a javascript object because of your use of `dataType : "json"`.  What does your console.log(json) produce.

Comment: @James its not showing anything on the console

Comment: Check the request/response in devtools network tab.

Comment: @James I dont see my ajax page there, but I do see my jsp page where the json is headed. And it shows the same thing [object Object]

Comment: @James  Thanks..solved it.